# Displaying text above Segmented buttons in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display text on top of Segmented buttons in bootstrap but, it is not working. The segmented buttons and the linked text box are wrapped using a form-group.

**Fiddler:**

https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/55/

```
<div class="col-md-3">                           
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label normal-text">Code<i class='asterisk'>*</i></label>
    <label class="control-label normal-text">Legacy</label>
    <label class="control-label normal-text">Actual</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CodeFilterTxtBox"/>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" name="revcode" id="LegacyCodeChkBox"/>17893
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" name="revcode" id="ActualCodeChkBox"/>34778
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Expectation:**

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the text Legacy and Actual in the html?

Comment: Good question :) Missed them in fiddle. Updated now.

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/56/)? Well it won't line up nicely if the length of number changes.

Comment: The length of the numbers will change....

Comment: Can you move the text, so make it as siblings of the radio buttons?

Comment: Updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/58/) text moved, next to the radio buttons.

Comment: @sdcr, your solution is actually working for me. You should have provided this in the answers section :)

Comment: Yep, just added as an answer, we love to see questions get solved :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add two `<span>` with the text inside, and make them to display above the radio buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/jL6x0apu/

```
.label-legacy,
.label-actual {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
}
```

Or to use pseudo `content` for the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/tjrwf7zo/

```
.label-legacy:before,
.label-actual:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
}
.label-legacy:before {
    content: "Legacy";
}
.label-actual:before {
    content: "Actual";
}
```

Check out the demos and see the comments in side.

Answer (score 1):

Give the labels absolute positioning:

```
.form-group label.control-label:nth-child(2),
.form-group label.control-label:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Then add this code:

```
$('.form-group label.control-label:nth-child(2)')
  .css('left', $('#LegacyCodeChkBox').offset().left);

$('.form-group label.control-label:nth-child(3)')
  .css('left', $('#ActualCodeChkBox').offset().left);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m90qnecy/)

Comment: Interesting answer. Let me try this logic in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I went about adding an attribute to the input, and placing it on top the button with the ::before pseudo-element selector.

```
input[type="radio"]::before{
content:attr(text);
position:absolute;
top: -50%;}
```

Mind the new "text" attributes on the input elements themselves.

https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/57/

Comment: good idea, but when i implemented this solution in my project, for some reason, the text (legacy  or actual) is not displaying in the UI. I see that the html complains text as not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use col inside to constrol size, even for input control and radio buttons, [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opvLk2qt/)

```html
div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label normal-text">Code<i class='asterisk'>*</i>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label normal-text">Legacy</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label normal-text">Actual</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CodeFilterTxtBox" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="revcode" id="LegacyCodeChkBox" />17893</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="revcode" id="ActualCodeChkBox" />34778</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```